# Pyinstaller executable keeps opening

Tags: python, pyinstaller

## Background

I am working on face recognition following [this link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/24/opencv-face-recognition/) and I would like to build a standalone application using Python. My `main.py` script looks like the following.

```
# main.py

# Import packages and other scripts
import tkinter as tk
...

# Some functions
def initialization():
    # OpenCV and sklearn are used here
    ...

def registration():
    # OpenCV, and sklearn are used here
    ...

def face_recognition():
    # OpenCV and sklearn are used here
    ...

# Start the Tkinter GUI
window = tk.Tk()

# Initialize the face recognition model
initialization()

# Input name for registration
tk.Label(window, text = "Name").grid(...)
entry1 = tk.Entry(window)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)

# When the button is clicked, different command is executed
tk.Button(window, text='Registration', command=registeration).grid(...) 
tk.Button(window, text='Face Recognition', command=face_recognition).grid(...)

window.mainloop()
```

Using python interpret to run the script (`python main.py`), everything works fine.

---

## Problem

I use **Pyinstaller** to convert the scripts to a single exe with this command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile \
            --windowed \
            --hidden-import sklearn.neighbors.typedefs \
            main.py
```

Then, I have two exe generated. The first one is in `dist/main` and the second one is in `dist/main.app/Contents/MacOS/main`

When running the exe, the exe keeps duplicate itself. I display the running process and found this result

```
$ ps
PID    TTY    TIME    CMD
...    ...    ...     /path/to/main -B -s -S -E -c from multiprocessing.semaphore_tracker import main:main(8)
...    ...    ...     /path/to/main -B -s -S -E -c from multiprocessing.semaphore_tracker import main:main(8)
...    ...    ...     /path/to/main -B -s -S -E -c from multiprocessing.semaphore_tracker import main:main(7)
...    ...    ...     /path/to/main -B -s -S -E -c from multiprocessing.semaphore_tracker import main:main(7)
...    ...    ...     /path/to/main -B -s -S -E -c from multiprocessing.semaphore_tracker import main:main(8)
```

I have no idea what happens to the exe since I do not import multiprocessing packages in my scripts. Any idea how to fix this problem? Thanks

---

**Update 1**

I added a `--log-level ERROR` when using `Pyinstaller` and gives this result. Not sure if it is related to my problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto.Math'
174598 INFO: MKL libraries found when importing numpy. Adding MKL to binaries
176282 ERROR: Can not find path ./libtbb.dylib (needed by /Users/user/anaconda3/lib/libmkl_tbb_thread.dylib)
```

---

**Update 2**

I found out that one of the packages that I am using -- `imultis` VideoStream involves `threading`. I guess it is the reason for observing `from multiprocessing.semaphore_tracker` as shown above even though I do not `import multiprocessing` explicitly.

Then I come across with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32672596/pyinstaller-loads-script-multiple-times/32677108#32677108), suggesting to add `multiprocessing.freeze_support()`.  It can suppress the GUI window from keep duplicating, but the background processes as shown using `$ ps` still keep duplicating. The problem has not fixed yet.

---

**Update 3 (Issue located but not fix)**

After debugging the code for quite a while, it turns out that the causes of this infinite looping is NOT due to the `threading` of `imultis` VideoStream (I write another script to test `imultis` and it is completely OK). But the problem comes from importing `sklearn`!!! This problem has been reported in GitHub in [this link](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3907).

This GitHub link also suggest to include `multiprocessing.freeze_support()`. Moreover one of the responses suggests to import `sklearn` after `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` is called. I try it with a simple script but the problem is still here.

**Conclusion**: `sklearn` causes the executable keeps opening. But I have no idea why it is the case, and I do not know how to solve it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: may be you need to use **waitkey** in your **main.py** to wait for some keys to destroy your window. And also use **destroyAllWindows**.

Answer (score 2):

I met the same issue. Scikit-learn provides a workaround.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#why-do-i-sometime-get-a-crash-freeze-with-n-jobs-1-under-osx-or-linux

I added below codes at the beginning of my script and fixed my issue:

```
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.set_start_method('forkserver', force=True)
multiprocessing.freeze_support()
```

Hope this can also fix yours.

Comment: Thanks. now the program does not fork processes infinitely But still, when I check the background process, it shows `/path/to/main -B -s -S -E -c from multiprocessing.semaphore_tracker import main:main(7)`. Any idea why there are such processes?

Answer (score 2):

This answer does a good job explaining why this happens: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55382641/109525

First try setting this before starting your program:

```
export JOBLIB_MULTIPROCESSING=0
```

If it works, you can add a runtime hook to your program to set the environment variable automatically. See: https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html#changing-runtime-behavior

Comment: I have the same issue with an app that uses `sklearn` and is built with `PyInstaller` for the Mac.  I was able to work around this issues by adding this at the start of my app:  

`if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    os.environ['JOBLIB_MULTIPROCESSING'] = '0'`

Answer (score 1):

Starting my main entry point with:

```
from multiprocessing import freeze_support
freeze_support()
```

Worked for me!

Comment: Worked perfectly! When trying to run a parallel process from within `wxpython` it just started a new UI instead. For reference, here's how I wrapped the UI function to make it work with multiprocessing:  `from multiprocessing import freeze_support; from my_gui import open_gui; freeze_support(); open_gui()` Then export this script with `pyinstaller`