# Fixing apparent recursion error while import sklearn in an embedded python application

Tags: python, c, scikit-learn

I'm trying to import sklearn in a C application with embedded python and it falls into what appears to be some sort of recursive loop.  Has anyone encountered this before and found a solution?

I've created the very simple application below.  When I execute it, I get a "FutureWarning", and then it appears that the application starts again.  Executing a python script with this import line has no problems; neither does executing it from the Python REPL.

```c
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%s\n",argv[0]);
    wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
    if (program == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: cannot decode argv[0]\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    Py_SetProgramName(program);  /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();

    PyObject *pName, *pModule;
    pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault("sklearn");

    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

    Py_Finalize();
    PyMem_RawFree(program);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output repeated over and over again until I exit:

./a
/home/wisp/anaconda3/envs/mpl-test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py:313: FutureWarning: numpy not_equal will not check object identity in the future. The comparison did not return the same result as suggested by the identity (`is`)) and will change.
  _nan_object_mask = _nan_object_array != _nan_object_array
/home/wisp/test-py/a
/home/wisp/anaconda3/envs/mpl-test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py:313: FutureWarning: numpy not_equal will not check object identity in the future. The comparison did not return the same result as suggested by the identity (`is`)) and will change.
  _nan_object_mask = _nan_object_array != _nan_object_array
/home/wisp/test-py/a
/home/wisp/anaconda3/envs/mpl-test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py:313: FutureWarning: numpy not_equal will not check object identity in the future. The comparison did not return the same result as suggested by the identity (`is`)) and will change.
  _nan_object_mask = _nan_object_array != _nan_object_array
..
..
..

The warning is expected based on my observations of the script and REPL; the continuous output is not.

Answer (score 0):

After taking a closer look at what processes were being spawn, it appears that the issue is directly related to this:
[Pyinstaller executable keeps opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54662306/pyinstaller-executable-keeps-opening).  Setting `export JOBLIB_MULTIPROCESSING=1` handles this issue.